# My FTP batch script is stuck on "200 PORT command successful" and doesn't upload the files to server

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, automation

I've tried everything I found in Google results about

> 200 PORT command successful

but nothing has helped.

Can anyone assist to solve this issue please?

**The code of "runScript.bat:**

```
ftp -s:"C:\automation\fileup.bat" myserver.com
```

**The code of "fileup.bat:**

```
username
password
ascii
cd "/public_html/reports/"
lcd "C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter"
prompt
mput *
disconnect
close
bye
```

**The console log:**

```
C:\automation>ftp -s:"C:\automation\fileup.bat" myserver.com
Connected to myserver.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 7 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 04:40. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
User (server26.000webhost.com:(none)):
331 User username OK. Password required

230-OK. Current restricted directory is /
230-449 files used (4%) - authorized: 10000 files
230 16742 Kbytes used (1%) - authorized: 1536000 Kb
ftp> ascii
200 TYPE is now ASCII
ftp> cd "/public_html/reports/"
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/reports
ftp> lcd "C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter"
Local directory now C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter.
ftp> prompt
Interactive mode Off .
ftp> mput *
200 PORT command successful
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This looks like a typical problem with the FTP active mode. The server cannot connect back to your machine to establish a data transfer connection.

That typically happens as nowadays most client machines are behind a firewall or NAT or both, what prevents the FTP active mode from working. To make the active mode working you need to open your firewall (not recommended) and/or configure NAT routing rules.

See my article on [FTP modes and configuring network for the active mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

---

Or you use the passive FTP mode. The Windows `ftp.exe` client does not support the passive mode though, what makes it pretty useless nowadays.

So you need to use another command-line FTP client. A majority of FTP clients do support the passive mode.

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) your `runScript.bat` would be like:

```
winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@myserver.com/" ^
    "cd /public_html/reports/" ^
    "lcd C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter" ^
    "put *" ^
    "exit"
```

Note that WinSCP defaults to the passive mode.

For details see WinSCP guides for:

- [Automating file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)
- [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp)

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem ("200 PORT command successful" stuck on the screen forever), and I was able to solve it.

First of all, there are lot of posts on the Internet saying that Windows ftp.exe doesn't support passive mode. This is not true:

ftp> quote pasv

227 Entering Passive Mode

In my case I had a Windows 2012 R2 server with a real IP. Switching to the passive mode didn't solve the problem, I was still stuck at "200 PORT command successful". At the same time WinSCP worked fine. The solution was to create an inbound firewall rule which allowed external connections from FTP server to the local ftp.exe.

Comment: A positive response to the `quote pasv` does not prove that Windows FTP does supports passive mode. It switches only the *server* to the passive mode, but not the *client*. The point of the `quote` command is that it sends an arbitrary command to the server, and the client does not even try to understand, what the command does. Hence the server is switched the passive mode and the client stays in the active mode. And transfers cannot work.